# Why the combination of model subclassing and TFRecord does not work?

Tags: keras, subclass, tfrecord

## The short version of the question

Why when I try to train a model which is implemented through subclassing (in Keras) using a dataset that is saved and loaded by TFRecord, it fails?

## The complete version of the question

I have the following model (first let's define in it functional API):

```py
def get_model():
    input_layer = Input(shape=(6,), name="input")

    x = input_layer

    x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name="dense_1")(x)
    x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', name="dense_2")(x)
    x = layers.Dense(5120, activation='relu', name="dense_3")(x)

    a_out = layers.Dense(17, activation='softmax', name='a_out')(x)
    b_out = layers.Dense(27, activation='softmax', name='b_out')(x)
    c_out = layers.Dense(71, activation='softmax', name='c_out')(x)
    d_out = layers.Dense(29, activation='softmax', name='d_out')(x)

    model = models.Model(input_layer, [a_out, b_out, c_out, d_out])

    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss=('sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                        'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                        'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                        'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'))
    
    return model
```

It takes in a tensor of shape (6,) and outputs 4 different outputs, `a_out`, `b_out`, `c_out`, and `d_out`. Each of which is an integer (categorical output). Next I'm going to define a dummy/random dataset to train this model with:

```py
sample_count = 1000
inputs = np.random.rand(sample_count, 6).astype(np.float32)
targets = (
    np.random.randint(low=0, high=16, size=(sample_count,), dtype=np.int64),
    np.random.randint(low=0, high=26, size=(sample_count,), dtype=np.int64),
    np.random.randint(low=0, high=70, size=(sample_count,), dtype=np.int64),
    np.random.randint(low=0, high=28, size=(sample_count,), dtype=np.int64)
)
random_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inputs, targets))

for rec in random_dataset:
    print(rec)
    break
```

If you call the functional API model's `fit` method and provide it with this dataset, it will train just fine. Also, the `print` statement from the previous code block outputs something like this:

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0.326234  , 0.9935627 , 0.65569717, 0.05908937, 0.7490394 ,
       0.7929646 ], dtype=float32)>, (<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([5])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([5])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([60])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([9])>))
```

Now, let's save and load the same dataset using TFRecord:

```py
# Saving the random dataset into a TFRecord file
def _bytes_feature(value):
    """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
    # If the value is an eager tensor BytesList won't unpack a string from an EagerTensor.
    if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))):
        value = value.numpy() 
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def _int64_feature(value):
    """Returns an int64_list from a bool / enum / int / uint."""
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

file_path = 'random.tfrec'
with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(file_path) as writer:
  for rec in random_dataset:
    feature = {
      'input': _bytes_feature(tf.io.serialize_tensor(rec[0])),
      'a_out': _int64_feature(rec[1][0]),
      'b_out': _int64_feature(rec[1][1]),
      'c_out': _int64_feature(rec[1][2]),
      'd_out': _int64_feature(rec[1][3]),
    }

    example_proto = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
    writer.write(example_proto.SerializeToString())

# Load the dataset off the file just created
def read_tfrecord(serialized_example):
    feature_description = {
        'input': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
        'a_out': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
        'b_out': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
        'c_out': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
        'd_out': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64)
    }

    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized_example, feature_description)

    return tf.io.parse_tensor(example['input'], out_type=tf.float32), (
        example["a_out"],
        example["b_out"],
        example["c_out"],
        example["d_out"])

tfrecord_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file_path).map(read_tfrecord)

for rec in tfrecord_dataset:
    print(rec)
    break
```

The last print statement is just a sanity check to make sure that the dataset was not distorted during the serialization process. It outputs something like:

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0.326234  , 0.9935627 , 0.65569717, 0.05908937, 0.7490394 ,
       0.7929646 ], dtype=float32)>, (<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([5])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([5])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([60])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([9])>))
```

which is identical in every way to the original dataset. And if I feed this `tfrecord_dataset` dataset to the functional API model, it still trains just fine. Next, I'm going to define the same model using inheritance (A.K.A. subclassing):

```py
class SubclassModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubclassModel, self).__init__()

        self.d1 = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name="dense_1")
        self.d2 = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', name="dense_2")
        self.d3 = layers.Dense(5120, activation='relu', name="dense_3")

        self.a_out = layers.Dense(17, activation='softmax', name='a_out')
        self.b_out = layers.Dense(27, activation='softmax', name='b_out')
        self.c_out = layers.Dense(71, activation='softmax', name='c_out')
        self.d_out = layers.Dense(29, activation='softmax', name='d_out')

        self.build((None, 6,))
        self.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                     loss=('sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                           'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                           'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                           'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'))

    def call(self, inputs, training=True):
        x = inputs
        
        x = self.d1(x)
        x = self.d2(x)
        x = self.d3(x)
        
        a = self.a_out(x)
        b = self.b_out(x)
        c = self.c_out(x)
        d = self.d_out(x)

        return a, b, c, d
```

Here's the punch line. Now, I have two different ways of creating the model (functional API and inheritance) and two different datasets (`random_dataset` and `tfrecord_dataset`). That makes up four different combinations:

1. Training functional API model using `random_dataset`: works fine
2. Training functional API model using `tfrecord_dataset`: works fine
3. Training SubclassModel using `random_dataset`: works fine
4. **Training SubclassModel using `tfrecord_dataset`: fails!**

Here's the error I face (truncated):

```
TypeError: in user code:

    File "/home/mehran/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 878, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/home/mehran/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 867, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/home/mehran/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/home/mehran/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 808, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/home/mehran/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

    TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "subclass_model_1" (type SubclassModel).
    
    in user code:
    
        File "/tmp/ipykernel_22298/1542980101.py", line 28, in call  *
            a = self.a_out(x)
        File "/home/mehran/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler  **
            raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
        File "/home/mehran/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/envs/jupyter/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/activations.py", line 78, in softmax
            if x.shape.rank > 1:
    
        TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "a_out" (type Dense).
        
        '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
        
        Call arguments received:
          • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=float32)
    
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=<unknown>, dtype=float32)
      • training=True
```

Does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who might be facing the same problem, the solution is to reshape the tensors to match their intended shape when you are reading the TFRecords:

```py
def read_tfrecord(serialized_example):
    feature_description = {
        'input': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
        'a_out': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
        'b_out': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
        'c_out': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
        'd_out': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64)
    }

    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized_example, feature_description)

    return tf.reshape(tf.io.parse_tensor(example['input'], out_type=tf.float32), (6,)), (
        example["a_out"],
        example["b_out"],
        example["c_out"],
        example["d_out"])
```

Why the functional API does not complain about this but the sub-classing does, is beyond me.